# Find difference between dates in df using python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have data

```
                   date                      id       request  
0   2016-06-22 03:00:48         upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1   
1   2016-06-22 03:02:52         upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1   
2   2016-06-22 03:03:48         upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1   
3   2016-06-22 03:05:15         upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1   
4   2016-06-22 03:05:55         upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1
```

and I want to count difference between `date`
I try

```
dates = df1['date']
for i, date in enumerate(dates):
    dates[i].to_datetime()
    d = (dates[i] - dates[i-1]).total_seconds()
```

But it returns

```
KeyError: -1L
```

Comment: try `enumerate(dates,1)` . enumerate starts from index 0 by default so your `(dates[i] - dates[i-1])` might call a nonexistent index

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?

```
In [130]: df
Out[130]:
                 date               id         request
0 2016-06-22 03:00:48  upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1
1 2016-06-22 03:02:52  upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1
2 2016-06-22 03:03:48  upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1
3 2016-06-22 03:05:15  upi88@yandex.ru  GET HTTP/1.1
4 2016-06-22 03:05:55  upi88@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1

In [131]: df.date.diff().dt.total_seconds()
Out[131]:
0      NaN
1    124.0
2     56.0
3     87.0
4     40.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

you code beginning index is 1 and i-1 is -1

```
dates = df1['date']
for i in range(1,len(dates)):
    dates[i].to_datetime()
    d = (dates[i] - dates[i-1]).total_seconds()
```